# How to add <ul> tag before <li> tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

Now output coming like that

```
 <li id="socialprofiles-2" class="widget social-profiles">
       <a href="http://www.facebook.com"></a>
       <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"></a>
 </li>
```

but i need want to do like that

```
 <ul>
 <li id="socialprofiles-2" class="widget social-profiles">
       <a href="http://www.facebook.com"></a>
       <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"></a>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

I am not getting how to do it in Jquery

Comment: And what does your Javascript code look like?

Comment: You should add that `ul` in the HTML, not with JS. Edit: because a `li` _must_ reside in a `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function:

```
$('#socialprofiles-2').wrap('<ul />');
```

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/iboxiq)** (You will have to use Firebug to inspect newly added `ul` element)

Comment: Notice that this will only work if every `<li>` should have it's own list.

Comment: Your solution seems to be sufficient, but the original code does get better by this. A li always needs to be inside of an ul, the validator won't accept a Javascript solution here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method, to wrap the selected element with another element. In your case, you could select your `li` through its ID:

```
$("#socialprofiles-2").wrap("<ul />");
```